# Smart way to filter out unnecessary rows from Query

Tags: postgresql, filter

So I have a query that shows a huge amount of mutations in postgres. The quality of data is bad and i have "cleaned" it as much as possible.

To make my report so user-friendly as possible I want to filter out some rows that I know the customer don't need.

I have following columns id, change_type, atr, module, value_old and value_new

For change_type = update i always want to show every row.
For the rest of the rows i want to build some kind of logic with a combination of atr and module.

For example if the change_type <> 'update' and concat atr and module is 'weightperson' than i don't want to show that row.

In this case id 3 and 11 are worthless and should not be shown.

Is this the best way to solve this or does anyone have another idea?

```
select * from t1
where concat(atr,module) not in ('weightperson','floorrentalcontract')
```

In the end my "not in" part will be filled with over 100 combinations and the query will not look good. Maybe a solution with a cte would make it look prettier and im also concerned about the perfomance..

```
CREATE TABLE t1(id integer, change_type text, atr text, module text, value_old text, value_new text) ;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES

(1,'create','id','person',null ,'9'),
(2,'create','username','person',null ,'abc'),
(3,'create','weight','person',null ,'60'),
(4,'update','id','order','4231' ,'4232'),
(5,'update','filename','document','first.jpg' ,'second.jpg'),
(6,'delete','id','rent','12' ,null),
(7,'delete','cost','rent','600' ,null),
(8,'create','id','rentalcontract',null ,'110'),
(9,'create','tenant','rentalcontract',null ,'Jack'),
(10,'create','rent','rentalcontract',null ,'420'),
(11,'create','floor','rentalcontract',null ,'1')
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QCuVf2Yk)

Comment: Why are rows with id 3 and 11 worthless? That logic should be in the query. The lack of a proper datamodel works against you and the database, this will cause issues.

Comment: @frankheikens i can't use the id since i don't know every id i want to hide. I need to hide rows with a combination of atr and module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the list of combinations in a separate table and join with that table, or have them listed directly in a `with`-clause like this:

```
with combinations_to_remove as (
        select *
        from (values
            ('weight', 'person'),
            ('floor' ,'rentalcontract')
        ) as t (atr, module)
    )
select t1.*
from t1
left join combinations_to_remove using(atr, module)
where combinations_to_remove.atr is null
```

I guess it would be cleaner and easier to maintain if you put them in a separate table!

Read more on [with-queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) if that sounds strange to you.